# ValidationException: ExpressionAttributeNames can only be specified when using expressions

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to add an item in a dynamodb table via a nodeJs labmda. I'm using the ExpressionAttributeNames to avoid collisions with reserved words but am getting the error: `ValidationException: ExpressionAttributeNames can only be specified when using expressions` Any suggestions on what I may be missing? I can't seem to find an example of using `putItem` with ExpressionAttributeNames.

```
  const params = {
    TableName: 'table',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      '#id': 'id',
      '#time': 'time',
    },
    Item: {
      '#id': { S: 'dfs' },
      '#time': { S: 'Now' },
    },
  };

 dynamodb.putItem(dynamodbPut)
```